# Https doesn't show in the server swagger UI

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, kubernetes

I  have a dockerfile where i have exposed port 8080 with http protocol, added the required parameters. The app is in dotnet. I have created a swagger ui using deployment file, service and ingress. It works fine when I hit the URL in https://example.org, but below all API requests goes in http only. I tried making change in Ingress for port forwarding, ssl redirect, backend protocol, nothing seems to be working. I tried making change in Dockerfile, that might be a issue, It gives me error everytime saying Unable to Configure HTTPS endpoint, even though i have generated the self-signed certificate.

Comment: When you have created the self singed cert you used the staging URL or production URL? also please feel free to add more details ingress route path or so get some config idea

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be in self-signed certificate? Browsers may not be accepting it. You can use Let's Encrypt, for example.

Comment: certificate works fine, i am using letsencrypt only